# Select specific columns from CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

My code is able to get the 28 columns of a text file and format/remove some data. How Can I select specific columns? The columns I want are 0 to 25, and column 28. What is the best approach?

Thanks in advance!

```
import csv
import os

my_file_name = os.path.abspath('NVG.txt')
cleaned_file = "cleanNVG.csv"
remove_words = ['INAC-EIM','-INAC','TO-INAC','TO_INAC','SHIP_TO-inac','SHIP_TOINAC']


with open(my_file_name, 'r', newline='') as infile, open(cleaned_file, 'w',newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    cr =  csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerow(next(cr)[:28])
    for line in (r[0:28] for r in cr):

        if not any(remove_word in element for element in line for remove_word in remove_words):
         line[11]= line[11][:5]

         writer.writerow(line)
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
import pandas as pd

usecols = list(range(26)) + [28]
data = pd.read_csv(my_file_name, usecols=usecols)
```

You can also conveniently write the data back to a new file

```
with open(cleaned_file, 'w') as f:
    data.to_csv(f)
```

Comment: `Pandas` makes data manipulation so simple and viable. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

exclude column 26 and column27 from row using `filter()`:

```
for row in cr:
    content = list(filter(lambda x: row.index(x) not in [25,26], row))
    # work with the selected columns content
```

Comment: If you has to call list anyways, why not just use a list comprehension here: `content = [x for x in cr if cr.index(x) not in [25, 26]]`

Comment: You probably meant to filter the row, not the reader. Now you'll exhaust the reader during first iteration of the for-loop. Using find is also wasteful, why not `enumerate()`?

Comment: @IljaEverilä yes, the `row`, fix the typo.Thanks!

Comment: @Ohjeah both works. Actually my first edit was using list comprehension  to get selected columns `indices =[x for x in range(28) if x not in (25,26)]`